# creating a set from given variables. how to get the object's key's values to correspond to names of given variables?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I'm trying to test a set of some given variables. To organize the set, I'm adding the variables as keys to an object.

I think I'm on the right track with dynamically adding the key in accordance to the variable name. How can I ensure that each key's value corresponds to the value of the original given number?

example:

```
var num1 = 43;
var num2 = 597;
var num3 = 5662682;
```

I'd like for my object to basically come out like this:

```
{num1: 43, num2: 597, num3: 5662682}
```

I've tried:

```
function makeObj () {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    obj["num" + i] = "num" + i;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

but obviously, does not reference the variable. it stores a useless string.

```
{ num1: 'num1', num2: 'num2', num3: 'num3' }
```

how would I get the value of the said variable (num1, num2, num3) to be the value of the key of the same name, inside of my object?

I should also add, I'm looking to do this with standard Javascript and/or prototyping. No libraries or anything like that.

Comment: Why not assign them directly to the object instead of to vars?

Comment: You can't treat a number of variables as a "group". You need to use an array, or an object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript dynamic variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use eval.

http://jsfiddle.net/afrievalt/w7fm3/

```
var num1 = 43;
var num2 = 597;
var num3 = 5663683;

function makeObj () {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    obj["num" + i] = eval("num" + i);
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Please don't tell Mr. Crockford I used eval.  http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/

@sabof and I like to use an array:

```
var nums = [];
nums.push(43);
nums.push(597);
nums.push(5663683);

function makeObj () {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i <= nums.length; i++) {
    obj["num" + (i+1)] = nums[i];
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this and the link to the blog post. I've known about eval, but am unfamiliar with its upsides and downsides right now, so I'll check that out.

Comment: About using an array, I didn't like it at first because the numbers were given to me as instantiated variables, but I see how it can be useful now as the use of the for-loop leaves us room to grow/shrink the array. Not that I had to use a for-loop if I stayed with objects.... 
And to use my given variables, all I'd have do is: nums.push(num1); nums.push(num2); nums.push(num3);